# How can I draw a blurring rectangle on the image?

Tags: c++, opencv, computer-vision, 2d, onmouseover

I find a code which allows you to draw a blurring rectangle on the cam

and I try to change it from draw a blurring rectangle on the cam to an image because I want draw a blurring rectangle on the image.

and this is my code

```
 #include < stdio.h>  
 #include < iostream>  
 #include < opencv2\opencv.hpp>  
 #include < opencv2/core/core.hpp>  
 #include < opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>  
 #include < opencv2/video/background_segm.hpp>  
 #include < opencv2\gpu\gpu.hpp>  
 #include < opencv2\legacy\legacy.hpp>  

 using namespace std;
 using namespace cv;

 bool selectObject = false;
 Rect selection;
 Point origin;
 int trackObject = 0;
 Mat image;

 static void onMouse(int event, int x, int y, int, void*)
 {
 if (selectObject)
{
    selection.x = MIN(x, origin.x);
    selection.y = MIN(y, origin.y);
    selection.width = std::abs(x - origin.x);
    selection.height = std::abs(y - origin.y);

    selection &= Rect(0, 0, image.cols, image.rows);
} 

switch (event)
{
case CV_EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:

    origin = Point(x, y);
    selection = Rect(x, y, 0, 0);
    selectObject = true;
    break;
case CV_EVENT_LBUTTONUP:
    selectObject = false;
    if (selection.width > 0 && selection.height > 0)
        trackObject = -1;
    break;

  }
}


 int main(void)
 {
Mat img;
img = imread("C:/Users/faho0odywbas/Desktop/test.jpg");
Mat frame;
namedWindow("Demo");
setMouseCallback("Demo", onMouse);

for (;;)
{

     frame.copyTo(image);


    if (selectObject && selection.width > 0 && selection.height > 0)
    {
        Mat roi(image, selection);
        bitwise_not(roi, roi);
        printf("%d %d %d %d\n", selection.x, selection.y, selection.width, selection.height);
    }
    while (1){
    imshow("Demo", img);

    if (waitKey(10) > 10)
        break;
    }
}

return 0;
 }
```

and the code shows the image, but I can't draw the rectangle on it !!

What I miss ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

i have made some modification on your source. almost done all you want!

```
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>

#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

bool selectObject = false;
Rect selection;
Point origin;
int msize = 5;
Mat image,blurredImage;

vector<Rect> blurredAreas;

static bool doMosaic( Mat img, int msize)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < img.cols-msize; i+=msize)
        for(int j = 0; j < img.rows-msize; j+=msize)
        {
            Rect r = Rect(i,j,msize,msize);
            Mat mosaic = img( r );
            mosaic.setTo(mean(mosaic));
        }
    return true;
}

static bool doBlur()
{
    for(size_t i = 0; i< blurredAreas.size(); i++)
    {
        Mat roi = blurredImage(selection);
        //GaussianBlur(roi,roi,Size(),5,5);
        doMosaic(roi,msize);
    }
    imshow("Demo", blurredImage);
    return true;
}



static void onMouse(int event, int x, int y, int, void*)
{
    switch (event)
    {
    case CV_EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:
        origin = Point(x, y);
        selectObject = true;
        break;
    case CV_EVENT_LBUTTONUP:
    {
        selectObject = false;
        blurredAreas.push_back(selection);
        doBlur();
        break;
    }
    }

    if (selectObject)
    {
        selection.x = MIN(x, origin.x);
        selection.y = MIN(y, origin.y);
        selection.width = std::abs(x - origin.x)+1;
        selection.height = std::abs(y - origin.y)+1;
        selection &= Rect(0, 0, image.cols, image.rows);

        if ( selection.width > 0 && selection.height > 0)
        {
            Mat blurredImagecopy;
            blurredImage.copyTo(blurredImagecopy);
            Mat roi = blurredImagecopy(selection);
            bitwise_not(roi, roi);
            imshow("Demo", blurredImagecopy);
        }
    }
}


int main(void)
{
    image = imread("test.jpg");
    image.copyTo(blurredImage);

    namedWindow("Demo");
    setMouseCallback("Demo", onMouse );

    imshow("Demo", image);

    while( true )
    {
        int key = waitKey(0);

        if( key == 27 )
            break;

        if( key == 's' ) // saves result image
        {
          imwrite("result.jpg",blurredImage);
        }

        if( key == 'i' ) // space key for clear blurred areas
        {
            msize +=5;
            image.copyTo(blurredImage);
            doBlur();
        }

        if( key == 'd' ) // space key for clear blurred areas
        {
            msize = msize == 5 ? 5 : msize - 5;
            image.copyTo(blurredImage);
            doBlur();
        }

        if( key == 32 ) // space key for clear blurred areas
        {
            blurredAreas.clear();
            image.copyTo(blurredImage);
            doBlur();
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot it works after I added the packages in the beginning of the code, but please can you convert this blurring rectangle to the pixels that inside the rectangular region that defined by the user should be blurred with Mosaic effect. The level of blur depends on the user specified value. For
example, you can use an integer variable to store it:
int blur_degree = 5
Here “blur_degree” defines the length of each Mosaic unit square, see figure
3. By default it is 5 pixels in length. So the bigger of the “blur_degree”, the
more blur of the selected region

Comment: i suggest you to open a new question. also suggest to take a look OpenCV offical [Q&A](http://answers.opencv.org/) site